# Unable to execute commands using Ride-Robot-SSH Library

Tags: python, ssh, robotframework

I am exploring options of using RIDE-Robot Framework for my Project. Here, I am using SSH Library.

I am trying to login into my server and then try to execute some commands

Manually, I am trying to login to the server and then give a sudo admin command and then execute the set of commands.

Using Ride- I am using Open Connection, Execute Command keywords

I am able to login to the server with the username and password, but I am not able to execute commands.

Can you please help me understand how to execute commands?

I am able to open Connection and Login with username and password.

**Paramiko**

```
import paramiko    

from paramiko import SSHClient

ssh = SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('10.184.59.41', username='******', password='*******')

shell=ssh.invoke_shell()

shell.settimeout(0.5)

ssh.exec_command("sudo -u tradmin -E bash")

ssh.exec_command("/ThomsonReuters/apps/hillfarber")
```

******Ride******

```
Open Connection    10.184.59.41
Login    ${username}    ${password}
Execute Command    sudo - u tradmin -E bash
${stdout}=     Execute Command     /ThomsonReuters/tools/bin/adsmon -key 29 -get IDBFeed  c205xcmpdfh01.ECP_TUL.IDBFeed.IDBFeed PageCount
```

Unable to execute the commands, no error is displayed

Comment: Using Paramiko also I was unable to execute command

Comment: What is hillfarber? perhaps you want 
 ssh.exec_command("./ThomsonReuters/apps/hillfarber")

Comment: Hillfarber is actually a folder related to my project. yeah I want to execute that command, prior to that I need to execute the sudo -u tradmin -E Bash command. None of these commands I am able to execute

Comment: The code I pasted above has 2 things, one related to Paramiko and other related to my code in Ride Robot Framework

Comment: Have you tried adding `sudo=True` and the `sudo_password=password` argumentsin the execute command?

Comment: Tried giving ssh.exec_command("sudo -u tradmin -E bash",sudo=True,sudo_password='password') and got an error that exec_command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sudo'

Answer (score 0):

Each invocation of `Execute Command` is in a new shell - thus the `sudo` from the first does not influence the user in the second. See the [keyword documentation](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command), it's suggested there to use `Write` and `Read` keywords for continuity of commands execution within the same shell.

Alternatively you could combine the two calls in a single command - `sudo ... adsmon ...`.

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to execute the below 2 commands in one single command, Command 1: sudo -u tradmin -E bash, 

command 2: /ThomsonReuters/tools/bin/adsmon -key 29 -get IDBFeed c205xcmpdfh01.ECP_TUL.IDBFeed.IDBFeed PageCount
Single Command: sudo -u tradmin -E bash ;/ThomsonReuters/tools/bin/adsmon -key 29 -get IDBFeed c205xcmpdfh01.ECP_TUL.IDBFeed.IDBFeed PageCount
I separate Command 1 and 2 by a semicolon, upon executing I see that the command 1 is getting executing. but the command 2 is not getting executed. Can you please confirm me on how to append both of these commands ?